# Rounding isn't working

Tags: java, compiler-errors, rounding

For Java homework, we need to compute the cos and sin values at each interval of pi/4 of the unit circle and print it out.But mines is rounding incorrectly, even though I used the rounding technique the instructions provided using the assignment of a double doubleName and doubleName = Math.round(doubleName* 100) / 100.0.

The outcome should be:

```
Radians: (cos, sin)  
0.0: 1.0, 0.0  
0.79: 0.7, 0.71  
1.57: 0.0, 1.0  
2.36: -0.71, 0.7  
3.14: -1.0, 0.0  
3.93: -0.7, -0.71  
4.71: 0.0, -1.0  
5.5: 0.71, -0.71
```

But my output is:

```
Radians: (cos, sin)  
0.0: 1.0, 0.0  
0.79: 0.7, 0.71  
1.58: -0.01, 1.0  
2.37: -0.72, 0.7  
3.16: -1.0, -0.02  
3.95: -0.69, -0.72  
4.74: 0.03, -1.0  
5.53: 0.73, -0.68
```

My code:

```java
public class UnitCircle extends ConsoleProgram {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Radians: (cos, sin)");
    for (double i = 0; i <= 2 * Math.PI; i += Math.PI / 4) {
      i = Math.round(i * 100.0) / 100.0;
      double x = Math.cos(i);
      x = Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
      double y = Math.sin(i);
      y = Math.round(y * 100.0) / 100.0;
      System.out.println(i + ": " + x + ", " + y);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You're changing `i` inside the loop, then adding `Math.PI` in the loop. That will not be accurate. You need a second variable to assign the rounded value of `i` to. (Generally, don't change the loop counter inside the loop tiself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't round i in calculation, only round it for display.

```
    for (double i = 0; i <= 2 * Math.PI; i += Math.PI / 4) {
          double x = Math.cos(i);
          x = Math.round(x * 100.0) / 100.0;
          double y = Math.sin(i);
          y = Math.round(y * 100.0) / 100.0;
          System.out.println(Math.round(i*100)/100.0 + ": " + x + ", " + y);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is 100% correct but the error in the output occurs due to the two lines written after the loop.You must first extract the value of i from the given loop.2nd step:write math.cos() or math.sin() as per the question and then round up the result to get the appropriate answer.The code you have shared above first finds the round value and then finds the cos/sin of the answer due to which the output deviates appreciably from the correct answer and you end up getting a wrong result.There is no need for me to share the code as it has been already shared by someone else and he has provided you the correct solution for the question .I just answered this question to give you a proper feedback about your code so that you can find the errors yourself and debug your code.
Thank you.